# UINavigationController (Inside a UITabBarController tab) losing stack when a UIViewController is presented modally

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a UITabBarController with 3 tabs. All of them have a UINavigationController inside with their current stack of UIViewControllers.
The problem occurs when I present a UIViewController from any view on top of the UITabBarController (Modally) and when the presented UIViewController is dismissed, the selected tab loses the stack of UIViewControllers previously presented.

Does anyone know if this is a lifecycle memory management to help with the performance of the iPhone? I've tested this with pretty good iPhones and simulators.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you presenting from the top view controller on the stack and not the tab bar controller or the navigation controller?

Comment: I always present from the topmost view controller, and it usually is the top stack of the navigation

Answer (score 0):

Me from the future. This occurs when dismissing the modal viewcontroller from parent modal viewcontrollers. The dismiss function should be called on the topmost viewcontroller to dismiss only the current screen